# Mistake in proving that fg is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

In a book on analysis(Curso de Análise Vol. 1 by E.L. Lima), the author first defines the oscillation of a bounded function $f$, on a set $X$ as:
$w(f;X)$=sup $f(X)$-inf $f(X)$. Then he proves that it can also be defined as $sup|f(x)-f(y)|;x,y$ in $X$. He concludes(let's call it theorem "Z") that $f$ is integrable if and only if given $\epsilon>0$, exists a partition $P={t_0,....,t_n}$, such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i(t_i-t_{i-1})<\epsilon$, where $w_i$ is the oscillation of f in $[t_{i-1},t_i]$. After that, he tries to prove that if both $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are integrable, then $fg$ is also integrable. The demonstration goes like this: Let $K$ be such that $|f(x)|\le K$ and $|g(x)|\le K$. Then let $P_0={t_0,t_1,...,t_n}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$, and $w_i(f), w_i(g), w_i(fg)$ the oscillations of those functions in each subinterval, and note that:

$|f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)|\le |f(x)||g(x)-g(y)|+|g(y)||f(x)-f(y)|\le K[w_i(f)+w_i(g)]$, which implies that $w_i(fg)\le K[w_i(f)+w_i(g)]$

Finally, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i(fg)(t_i-t_{i-1})\le K[\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i(f)(t_i-t_{i-1})+\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i(g)(t_i-t_{i-1})]$, where he says "By Theorem Z, we conclude what we wished". As far as I understand, he expects me to apply Theorem Z with $\epsilon/2K$ twice, one with f and one with g. Nevertheless, each of the two partitions determined depends on the value $\epsilon/2K$, and they may not be the same. I expect your help, and sorry if I wrote too much.

Here is the relevant text from the book.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your actual question is.

Comment: He first fixes $P_0$ to prove all the inequalities, which I think they are all true. The problem is that when I apply Theorem Z at the end, by giving the $\epsilon/2K$ to f it determines a partition $P_1$, and by giving it to g, it determines another partition $P_2$. So all the inequalites are useless, because it can perfectly be $P_1\not = P_2$

Comment: I've edited the question to add the text from the book. I hope this helps to clarify things. The edit won't appear until it's been reviewed.

Comment: (1) What are $S(f;P)$ and $s(f;P)$ in Theorem 4? I think there could be something important there. (2) A minor point. After defining $w(f;X)$ it would be consistent and simpler to write $w(f;[t_{i-1},t_i])$ instead of  $w_i(f)(t_i-t_{i-1})$ which, if read literally, is meaningless because $ t_{i-1}-t_i$ is a number,not an interval.I see  that this occurs in the book.

Comment: Indeed, $t_i-t_{i-1}$ is a number. What he does is multiplicate each interval of the partition by his oscilation. Anyway, the question is already solved. Thanks for interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you appear to be correct that there is a problem with the proof. However, the quantity
$$\sum \omega_i(f) (t_i - t_{i-1})$$
only decreases when a refinement of the partition $\{t_0, t_1, \dots, t_n\}$ is selected. So the proof is correct if you choose a partition that is a common refinement of the partitions that work (with respect to $\epsilon/2K$) for each of $f$ and $g$.

Is it possible that this fact is mentioned earlier in the text?

Comment: Not explicity:It was proved that a refinement of a partition didn't increase the Upper sum and also didn't decrease the Lower sum. However, I get your point. Thank you very much!